# Sum an IIF in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

Is it possible to sum an IIF statment in MDX?

Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
With
Member [dim something].[group].[Summed] as
Sum(
iif( [dim something].[date one] = [dim date].[specific date],1,0)
   )

Select  [dim something].[group].[summed] on 0,
        [dim date].[specific date].members on 1

From    [Cube]
```

I know this does not work, just trying to show what I am trying to do. I want to evaluate a condition and return a 1 or zero based on that condition. Then sum or count the number of times it was returned as 1

Fairly new to MDX, coming from a SQL background it's very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF `[dim something].[date one]` is every only one date for your query then it would be something like the following

```
SELECT [Measures].[Some count] on 0
FROM [CUBE]
WHERE [dim date].[specific date]
```

Comment: I am having a hard time breaking out of the "Relational" mindset, I ended up putting this logic in my DSV as a flag which I can sum on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

its hard to know what you really want but there are mdx functions on SSAS to sum values based on dates.

The main one is YTD:

```
Sum(YTD([Dimension].[Calendar].CurrentMember),[Measures].[summed])
```

Comment: I'm trying to count how many times a condition in my IIF statement is true.